# Приём данных с COM порта в автоматическом режиме

Tags: c#, com-port, rs232

Суть проблемы в следующем:

К одному COM порту подключен разветвитель на 6 приборов.

По тику таймера, раз в секунду, программа автоматом должна опросить и получить информацию с каждого прибора. Скорость обмена данными 9600 бод, скорость увеличить нельзя. 

Для приёма данных использую стандартное событие Data_Recieved.

Теперь проблема: отправляется запрос -> приходит ответ, сообщение которого относительно длинное, немногим больше 500 байт (содержит различные коэффициенты и калибровочные данные прибора). 

Получается так, что запись ответа в переменную буфера сообщения прерывается выполнением следующего кода - условной конструкции, которая должна  проверить длину сообщения в этой переменной. Следовательно, по большей части, проверка не пройдена, т.к. сообщение в переменной было неполное. Единственный костыль, который помог - остановка основного потока на 30 мс, чтобы сообщение успело записаться в переменную.

 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно грамотно сделать приостановку выполнения дальнейшего кода, до момента пока полностью не выполнится запись сообщения в переменную?

И ещё, получается так, что за 1 секунду программа не успевает опрашивать все 6 приборов, получать и расшифровывать с них данные. Это проблема по большей части может быть связана со скоростью обмена данными, либо с плохим кодом?
Может кто сталкивался с этим и подскажет какой-то лучший подход?

 P.S. пробовал вариант, когда в обработчике события Data_Recieved_Handler(...){} через булевое свойство устанавливал флаг плана IsDataReceived, а в основном коде, в условной конструкции шла проверка этого флага, и в случае истинности выполнялся код по присвоению переменной сообщения.
В итоге: всё то же самое, событие принятия сообщения отрабатывает всё-равно медленнее и тело условной конструкции не отрабатывает..

Пример кода:
Первый вариант:

```
string bufferStr;
SerialPort port;
byte[] command = {0, 1, 2, ...};

public bool IsInputMessageChecked
{
    get; set;
}


private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    bufferStr = sp.ReadLine();  
}

public void GetDeviceConfigurationMessage(int deviceID)
{
    if(deviceID == 1)
    {
        port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
        //Проверка условия ниже выполняется быстрее, чем обработчик Port_DataReceived
        //Следовательно, условие всегда возвращает false
        //Не исключаю, что необходимо проверять другое условие, а не длину сообщения
        if(bufferStr.Length == 500)
        {                
            IsInputMessageChecked = CheckInputMessage(bufferStr);
        }
        ...
    }        
}
.....
```

Второй вариант пробовал так:

```
string bufferStr;
SerialPort port;
byte[] command = {0, 1, 2, ...};

public bool IsInputMessageChecked
{
    get; set;
}

public bool IsDataReceived
{
    get; set;
}

private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    IsDataReceived = true;
}

public void GetDeviceConfigurationMessage(int deviceID)
{
    if(deviceID == 1)
    {
        port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

        if(IsDataReceived) // Зачастую возвращает false
        {         
            bufferStr = port.ReadLine();     
            IsInputMessageChecked = CheckInputMessage(bufferStr);
        }
        ...
    }        
}
.....
```

Единственное, что помогает - вставлять после отправки команды паузу потока
    Thread.Sleep

Спасибо за ответы, но всё же, на будущее хотелось бы услышать адекватный подход считывания входящих данных, используя один порт, когда автоматом прогоняется код опроса и приёма данных с каждого прибора по очереди, чтобы никакие команды не перебивали друг друга!?

Comment: весьма сложно ответить не видя кода, я, честно говоря. запутался, читая ваш текст, может вместо этого выложите минимальный код и небольшое пояснение, что вас не устраивает и где?

Comment: _"за 1 секунду программа не успевает опрашивать все 6 приборов"_ Ваши пакеты имеют размер 500 байт, минимальная размерность получаемых битов на 1 байт = 10 (1 стартовый + 8 дата + 1 стоповый). Делим общее число получаемых битов на скорость и имеем, что для приемы одного пакета требуется 521 мс. и это без учёта времени на отправку самого запроса. Так что принять от 6 приборов за 1 с не получиться, максимум можете успееть обработать 3 запроса за 2 секунды.

Comment: Если скорость последовательного опроса слишком мала и не устраивает, то нужно распараллеливать процесс, а это нужно каждое устройство на разный порт вешать. Если портов не хватает, то нужно делать буфер, самой дешовой ардуины вполне хватит, которая будет опрашивать устройство и по высокой скорости через USB будет передавать в программу.

Comment: @Maks А еще можно купить за тыщу рублей переходник USB<->COM на шесть портов и тогда в системе появится шесть виртуальных COM-портов. Быстро кидаете каждому прибору запросы и приборы Вам передают данные, которые падают в шесть буферов виртуальных COM-портов. Вполне за полсекунды можно успеть, конечно если запросы не слишком длинные.

Comment: Сделайте `Singleton` и в нём запустите поток `Thread` в который добавьте цикл `while(true)`. А там опрашивайте свои устройства с любой периодичностью. Полученные данные пишите куда хотите. Задержки делайте любые. Самое главное уложитесь в 1 секунду. Т.е. 1000 / 6 = 166мс на каждое устройство. 150мс задержка на получение ответа, остальную погрешность можете компенсировать в общую задержку в конце прохода. Ивенты для `SerialPort` использовать не советую. Они могут срабатывать либо с каждого принятого байта, а могут через один. Для одновременного опроса вам нужен COM-USB адаптер (6шт.).